# What is the general consensus on "Useless use of cat"?

Tags: command-line, unix, pipe, cat

When I pipe multiple unix commands such as grep, sed, tr etc. I tend to specify the input file that is being processed using cat. So something like `cat file | grep ... | awk ... | sed ...` .

But recently after a couple of comments left on my answers indicating that this was a useless use of cat, I thought I would ask the question here.

I looked up the issue and came across [Wikipedia's article on UUOC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat) and [The Useless Use of Cat Award](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html) and it seems to me that the arguments made are from the perspective of efficiency.

The closest question I came across here was this one: [Is it wasteful to call cat?](https://superuser.com/questions/307650/is-it-wasteful-to-call-cat) – but it's not quite what I'm asking.

I guess what the UUOC camp suggest is to use `cmd1 args < file | cmd2 args | cmd3 ..` or if the command has an option to read from file then to pass in the file as an argument.

But to me `cat file | cmd1 ... | cmd2` seems much easier to read and understand. I don't have to remember different ways of sending input files to different commands, and the process flows logically from left to right. First input, then the first process ... and so on.

Am I failing to understand what arguments are being made about the useless use of cat? I understand that if I'm running a cron job that runs every 2 seconds that does a lot of processing, then in that case cat might be wasteful. But otherwise what's the general consensus on the use of cat?

Comment: I agree, here, the call to cat may be inefficient, but it makes the command much easier to understand and edit later, and (importantly, IMO) seperates each different command to having just one job, making the whole thing much easier to deal with.

Comment: The general consensus is that there is no consensus.

Comment: This largely duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat (though it predates it).

Comment: Don't forget that `< file cmd1 args | cmd2 args ...` works too... so your argument of "_left to right_" is void. I often use it for clarity - the order I showed can cause people to pause, which isn't good. With higher thread counts becoming the norm, this is becoming less of an issue IMO...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's useless in the sense that using it like that doesn't accomplish anything the other, possibly more efficient options can't (i.e. producing proper results).

But `cat` is way more powerful than just `cat somefile`. Consult `man cat` or read [what I wrote in this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/277680/is-backwards-redirection-the-same-as-a-pipe/277681#277681). But if you absolutely positively only need the contents of a single file, you might get some performance advantage from not using `cat` to get at the file contents.

Regarding readability, this depends on your personal tastes. I like `cat`ing files into other commands for the same reason, especially if the performance aspects are negligible.

It also depends on what you're scripting. If it's your own shell and convenience methods for your desktop machine, nobody except you will care. If you stumble upon a case where the next tool in the chain would be better off being able to seek, and distribute this as a frequently used piece of software on some minimal Linux system on a low-performance router or similar device with real limits on processing ability, that's different. It always depends on the context.

Comment: Are the performance costs are negligible? In many cases they are: http://oletange.blogspot.dk/2013/10/useless-use-of-cat.html

Answer (score 29):

I often use `cat file | myprogram` in examples. Sometimes I am being accused of Useless use of cat (http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html). I disagree for the following reasons:

**It is easy to understand what is going on.**

When reading a UNIX command you expect a command followed by
arguments followed by redirection. It *is* possible to put the
redirection anywhere but it is rarely seen - thus people will have a
harder time reading the example. I believe

```
    cat foo | program1 -o option -b option | program2
```

is easier to read than

```
    program1 -o option -b option < foo | program2
```

If you move the redirection to
the start you are confusing people who are not used to this syntax:

```
    < foo program1 -o option -b option | program2
```

and examples should
be easy to understand.

**It is easy to change.**

If you know the program can read from cat, you can normally assume it can read the output from any program that outputs to STDOUT, and thus you can adapt it for your own needs and get predictable results.

**It stresses that the program does not fail, if STDIN is not a regular file.**

It is not safe to assume that if `program1 < foo` works then `cat foo | program1` will also work. However, it *is* in practice safe to assume the opposite. This program works if STDIN is a file, but fails if the input is a pipe, because it uses seek:

```
    # works
    < foo perl -e 'seek(STDIN,1,1) || die;print <STDIN>'

    # fails
    cat foo | perl -e 'seek(STDIN,1,1) || die;print <STDIN>'
```

**Performance penalty is often not measurable.**

I have looked at the performance penalty on http://oletange.blogspot.dk/2013/10/useless-use-of-cat.html The conclusion is don't use `cat file |` if the complexity of the processing is similar to a simple grep and performance matters more than readability. For other situations `cat file |` is fine.

Here is an example where `| cat` *increases* performance by 50%:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/614154/useless-use-of-cat-increases-performance-why

Comment: Finally an answer with actual benchmarks.  I also note on my comment here that "sometimes" cat can be faster.  The only time I can imagine "useless use of cat" being an actual detriment is if you're doing trivial processing for huuuge files (or if the process can make special use of stdin like the tail command)... https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/225608/8337

Comment: There's circularity where you say "people who are not used to this syntax". By not using `<foo prog` in your examples you keep users unfamiliar with the syntax and you promote UUOC. Then you choose UUOC over `<foo prog` because users are unfamiliar with the latter. *You* keep them unfamiliar. Examples should teach. Total newbies know neither `<foo` nor `cat foo |`, IMO neither is easier to understand. Others may be biased because of UUOC acolytes. More: examples should teach right things. I'm not saying UUOC is not right; I'm saying your reasoning is flawed. Upvoted for everything else though.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski When teaching a concept, you should focus on what you are trying to teach without introducing new concepts that are not required for the concept you are teaching. My audience are not total newbies, but know `cat foo |`. If, however, I introduced `program1 -o <foo option -b option` without explaining that `<foo` can be anywhere on the line (even in the middle of `-o option`), I would be removing focus from what is important in my examples. Your criticism would be valid if I was introducing newbies to redirection, but I am not.

Comment: The question basically is "is UUOC as bad as its press?". *If* it's bad then we should the more teach users a better alternative. Your approach creates a feedback loop that amplifies UUOC. My point is: should the fact we let `cat foo |` be widely known and `<foo` be widely unknown be an argument for "UUOC is not bad"? If UUOC is not bad for other reasons then an extra argument for "not bad" is not needed. But *if* it's bad for other reasons then your approach is a vicious circle. You may not want to break it, I understand; but IMO it shouldn't be used to *support a claim* that UUOC is not bad.

Comment: I'm not too happy with the benchmark because it omitted the cases where there is a huge difference between `cat` and `<`. E.g. programs that automatically use `seek` if available (`tail -c` can seek directly to the relevant part instead of reading everything; `wc -c` boils down to `stat -c%s`; `sort` automatically switches to multi-threading) or scripts that repeatedly call `cat`/`<` and therefore amplify the not so small amount of time it takes to spin up another process. Try `time for i in {1..9999}; do cat f | true; done`. With `cat` 31s. With `<` 0.07s.

Comment: @Socowi The answer is for the general case - not for specialized programs. For programs that work faster on `<` it should be stressed in the man page for that program, and as a comment when used in a script. (Try replacing `true` with `/bin/true` and `sort` with `parsort` in your example).

Comment: I don't see how `wc -c` is any more specialized than `grep`. Regarding the loop: Of course the relative difference is smaller with `/bin/true` (`>`/`cat`=48s/76s=60% is still a big difference). I intentionally used a built-in since I wanted to measure just the overhead of `cat` rather than hiding this overhead behind other slowdowns. Example: With `for... sleep 1; cat f | /bin/true; done` the difference shrinks to `>`/`cat`=10048s/10075s=99.7%. But I hope we both can agree that such a "benchmark" is heavily distorted by `sleep 1`. Same goes for `true` vs. `/bin/true`.

Comment: @Socowi Again: `grep` is simply taken as an example.  It is chosen because most people will have an idea of the amount of work `grep` does (which is also why I write: "complexity of the processing is *similar to* a simple grep"). You should feel free to read `grep` as `foo`, where you do not know exactly how `foo` works.

Comment: @Socowi If you feel there is a market for benchmarks for special cases, I will encourage you to publish those.

Comment: @rogerdpack What is `tail` doing specially for `stdin`? I can't see anything obvious in the man page for that.

Comment: @Pod looks like if `tail` is given a "filename" (instead of pipe through to `stdin`)  then it can read the "last portion" of that file (seek to the end, read "backwards-ish"), so it doesn't have to process the first portion of the file at all.  Looks like when I wrote "my comment on here" I meant on the link question https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/225608/8337

Comment: I really liked the "Its easy to change point". I usually use the "useless cat" as a "placeholder cat". The text i am manipulating is currently coming from a file. But it will eventually come from another source. That could mean a server, another script, a cron job, etc. I see "cat input" as a placeholder for "The input to this chain of pipes should go here"

Answer (score 17):

In every day command line use it's not really much different. You especially aren't going to notice any speed difference since the time on CPU avoided by not using `cat`, your CPU is just going to be idle. Even if you're looping through hundreds or thousands (or even hundreds of thousands) of items in all practicality it's not going to make *much* difference, unless you're on a very loaded system (Load Average / N CPU > 1).

The where the rubber meets the road is about forming good habits and discouraging bad ones. To drag out a moldy cliché, the devil is in the details. And it's details like this that separate the mediocre from the great.

It's like while driving a car, why make a left turn when you can just make three rights instead? Of course you can, and it works perfectly. But if you understood the power of left turns then three rights just seems silly.

It's not about saving one file handle, 17k of RAM and 0.004 seconds of CPU time. It's about the entire philosophy of using UNIX. The "power of left turns" in my illustration isn't merely redirecting input, it's the UNIX philosophy. Fully understanding this will make you excel far better than those around you, and you will garner respect from those who do understand.

Comment: If you are thinking about turning left onto a 6-lane busy highway without a traffic light, then it may behoove you to consider turning right, or taking a different route.  *nix gives you the choice of several routes.   It is a matter of personal preference and readability.  If you want to "cat file | cmd1 | cat | cmd2 |more", go ahead.  (Sometimes that is useful if cmd1 paginates - cat will eliminate it.)  $CPU time << $Brain time.

Comment: @MikeP The `cat` will not eliminate any pagination, though piping to *something* might eliminate paging by some applications.

Comment: In fact, UPS trucks avoid turning left at nearly all costs, strengthening @MikeP's case above. https://theconversation.com/why-ups-drivers-dont-turn-left-and-you-probably-shouldnt-either-71432 It's a question of what you are optimizing for.

Comment: "You especially aren't going to notice any speed difference since the time on CPU avoided by not using cat, your CPU is just going to be idle." If you still believe you will not notice any speed difference, please explain why `cat` increases throughput by 50% https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/614154/useless-use-of-cat-increases-performance-why

Comment: @OleTange Wow, this is an old one! My point was more that in almost all cases, time spent trying to optimize out use of cat is going to far outweigh runtime differences, except in the most extreme cases, and as your experiment proves (very nice, btw!) there are counter examples. My opinion is that it's more about the tao than the performance but if perf matters, profile first, then optimize appropriately.

Answer (score 13):

I think the position being taken by some of those commenting on something being a UUOC is that if one really understands Unix and shell syntax, one would not use cat in that context. It's seen as like using poor grammar: I can write a sentence using poor grammar and still get my point across, but I also demonstrate my poor understanding of the language and by extension, my poor education. So saying that something is a UUOC is another way of saying someone doesn't understand what they're doing.

As far as efficiency goes, if you are executing a pipeline from the command line, it takes less time for the machine to execute `cat somefile |` than it does for you to think about whether it might be more efficient to use `< somefile`. It just doesn't matter.

Comment: For quite a while I've known that there were other ways to express `cat somefile | prog` in shell without cat, like `prog < somefile` but they always seemed to be in the wrong order to me, particularly with a chain of commands piped together. Now I see that something as elegant as `< somefile prog` does the trick, thank you. I have run out of the excuses I had left to use cat.

Answer (score 6):

I was not aware of the award until today when some rookie tried to pin the UUOC on me for one of my answers. It was a `cat file.txt | grep foo | cut ... | cut ...`. I gave him a piece of my mind, and only after doing so visited the link he gave me referring to the origins of the award and the practice of doing so. Further searching led me to this question. Somewhat unfortunately despite conscious consideration none of the answers included my rationale.

I did not meant to be defensive when educating him. After all, in my younger years I would have written the command as `grep foo file.txt | cut ... | cut ...` because whenever you do the frequent single `grep`s you learn the placement of the file argument and it is ready knowledge that the first is the pattern and the later ones are file names.

It was a conscious choice when I answered the question with the `cat` prefix partly because of a reason of "good taste" (in the words of Linus Torvalds) but chiefly for a compelling reason of function.

The latter reason is more important so I will put it out first. When I offer a pipeline as a solution I expect it to be reusable. It is quite likely that a pipeline would be added at the end of or spliced into another pipeline. In that case having a file argument to grep screws up reusability, and quite possibly do so *silently* without an error message if the file argument exists. I. e. `grep foo xyz | grep bar xyz | wc` will give you how many lines in `xyz` contain `bar` while you are expecting the number of lines that contain both `foo` and `bar`. Having to change arguments to a command in a pipeline before using it is prone to errors. Add to it the possibility of silent failures and it becomes a particularly insidious practice.

The former reason is not unimportant either since a lot of "good taste" merely is an intuitive subconscious rationale for things like the silent failures above that you cannot think of right at the moment when some person in need of education says "but isn't that cat useless".

However, I will try to also make conscious the former "good taste" reason I mentioned. That reason has to do with the orthogonal design spirit of Unix. `grep` does not `cut` and `ls` does not `grep`. Therefore at the very least `grep foo file1 file2 file3` goes against the design spirit. The orthogonal way of doing it is `cat file1 file2 file3 | grep foo`. Now, `grep foo file1` is merely a special case of `grep foo file1 file2 file3`, and if you do not treat it the same you are at least using up brain clock cycles trying to avoid the useless cat award.

That leads us to the argument that `grep foo file1 file2 file3` is concatenating, and `cat` concatenates so it is proper to `cat file1 file2 file3` but because `cat` is not concatenating in `cat file1 | grep foo` therefore we are violating the spirit of both the `cat` and the almighty Unix. Well, if that were the case then Unix would need a different command to read the output of one file and spit it to stdout (not paginate it or anything just a pure spit to stdout). So you would have the situation where you say `cat file1 file2` or you say `dog file1` and conscientiously remember to avoid `cat file1` to avoid getting the award, while also avoiding `dog file1 file2` since hopefully the design of `dog` would throw an error if multiple files are specified.

Hopefully at this point you sympathize with the Unix designers for not including a separate command to spit a file to stdout, while also naming `cat` for concatenate rather than giving  it some other name. **`<edit>`** there is such a dog, the unfortunate `<` operator. It is unfortunate its placement at the end of the pipeline preventing easy composability. There is no syntactically or aesthetically clean way to place it at the beginning. It is also unfortunate in not being general enough so you start with the dog but simply add another filename if you also want it to be processed after the previous one. (The `>` on the other hand is not half as bad. It has almost perfect placement at the end. It is typically not a reusable part of a pipeline, and accordingly it is distinguished symbolically.)**`</edit>`**

The next question is why is it important to have commands that merely spit a file or the concatenation of several files to stdout, without any further processing? One reason is to avoid having every single Unix command that operates on standard input to know how to parse at least one command line file argument and use it as input if it exists. The second reason is to avoid users having to remember: (a) where the filename arguments go; and (b) avoid the silent pipeline bug as mentioned above.

That brings us to why `grep` does have the extra logic. The rationale is to allow user-fluency for commands that are used frequently and on a *stand-alone* basis (rather than as a pipeline). It is a slight compromise of orthogonality for a significant gain in usability. Not all commands should be designed this way and commands that are not frequently used should completely avoid the extra logic of file arguments (remember extra logic leads to unnecessary fragility (the possibility of a bug)). The exception is to allow file arguments like in the case of `grep`. (by the way note that `ls` has a completely different reason to not just accept but pretty much require file arguments)

Finally, what could have been done better is if such exceptional commands as `grep` (but not necessarily `ls`) generate an error if the standard input is available. This is reasonable because the commands include logic that violates the orthogonal spirit of the almighty Unix for user convenience. For further user convenience, i. e. for preventing the suffering caused by a silent failure, such commands should not hesitate to violate their own violation by alerting the user if there is a possibility of silent failure.

Comment: As discussed on the cross-site duplicate of this answer and question, [`grep pattern f1 f2 f3` is not simple concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat#comment23911830_16619430).  `grep` knows about files, and prints filenames (and optionally line numbers, and whatever else).  `grep .  /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/*` is a nice hack for printing filename: file-contents with lots of single-line files.  The classic Unix design is that most utilities work on `*.txt` without needing `cat`.  `cat` is for flattening multiple files into one stream.

Comment: @PeterCordes I didn't write so much just about grep. There are substantive issues that I have observed regarding robustness to errors / copy-paste; correctness vs performance, that you have conveniently chose to ignore in favor of some petty/peripheral concern.

Comment: You do make some interesting and valid points, especially about the errors you can get when copy/pasting pipelines.  I'd suggest replace your `grep` example with a program like `cut` that doesn't have any reason to care about multiple files, and could always just be fed from its stdin.  Some utilities, like `tr`, don't accept file args at all, and only work as a filter, so the choice is between `cat` and `<`.

Comment: My biggest problem with your post is that you discount input redirection.   `<file  cmd1 | cmd2 >out` is not wonderful, I admit, but it's totally possible to get used to it.  You keep going on about "the spirit of the almighty Unix" in a mocking way, which totally falls flat for me because it sounds like you either don't get or don't want to get the way the Unix designers really did think.  It's fine if you don't like the Unix design, but it's not inherently dumb.  I'm not sure if the design of the OS predates shell syntax, and how it all evolved, but an extra `cat` in 1970 was worth avoiding!

Comment: Another way to look at it: `<` or filename args are an optimization you can apply for the special case of a single file, or the special case of a command that accepts args. Many people like to write efficient programs or scripts, even when the difference doesn't *really* matter much. Being militantly opposed to optimizations is unjustified, especially when the methods for exposing them evolved from 1970 onward when they were actually useful. I understand that it gets annoying on the Internet, because computer geeks have a hard time *not* pointing out tangential things they notice all the time.

Comment: @PeterCordes In hindsight I was rather long-winded in my answer, which detracts from the most important point -- correctness first, optimization second. The extra `cat` helps reuse and splice pipelines, whereas without it you can get silent failures (search for "silently" in my answer).

Comment: Yes, that's a useful and valid point, especially if you're used to using `cat` this way already.  I downvoted because of all the bogus stuff detracting from this good point.  Better examples would support this point much better.  Also, you need to make it clear that you're talking about modern Unix practice, and lament that modern Unix still hasn't come up with anything better than what the Unix kernel + Bourne shell had since the early days: the optional and (back then) useful optimization of redirecting input instead of using `cat` for a single file.

Comment: OK. I'll edit it down someday; most of the verbiage was motivated by outrage at some clueless newbie handing out uuoc awards without having any comprehension of the subtleties. (sounded like a millenial or someone born well after unix and computers were powerful enough to obviate optimization ahead of correctness). anyway, glad you see the central point; downvote is fine since the gentleman on stackoverflow accepted this as correct on that version of the QA.

Comment: @PeterCordes on a separate note, i wonder if `cat` itself could be optimized such that if it has just one arg it can merely dup that fd to its output, or something like that (and if the unix kernel doesn't support that, then it could be optimized to do so). i haven't done much unix coding lately to know if that makes sense, but just a thought.

Answer (score 5):

**In defense of Useless Uses of Cat**

(A few paragraph to help balance the tsunami of nagging comments against this practice)

I've been using bash for too many years both as a shell and as a scripting language for small scripts (and sometimes regretfully for not so small ones). A long-long time ago I've learned about the "Useless Use of Cat" (UUoC). I'm still *guilty* of it at least every week but frankly I rarely feel even a tiny bit compelled to avoid it. I believe that using `cat` vs `< file` is more about taste than technical differences and I wrote this answer to protect people new to Linux that share my taste for `cat` from thinking that there's something seriously wrong about their way (and note the few occasions where there is). Like Linus Torvalds I also believe that often taste is more important than skill. That doesn't mean that my taste is better than yours but it does mean that if something tastes bad I will not do it without gaining something worthy.

It's already obvious that like the question author *I feel* that using cat is very natural when working on a REPL like bash where I'm exploring a problem by incrementally constructing complex commands. Here's a very typical example: I have a text file and don't know much about it. I will type `cat file` to get a taste of the contents. *If* the output is too much I'll hit my up arrow and depending on the circumstances I'll add `| head` or `| grep foo` or `| what_ever` extending my previous command by appending processing steps. This way of incrementally going from a simple command to a more complex one by adding one processing step after the other feels very natural to me (I'm doing the same on ipython and I love the way `pyfunctional` and similar programming tools encompass this style). So when working on the bash shell *I*'m confident that interrupting my flow to remove the `cat` is *more useless* than let it be and suffer ... well no consequence at all in 99.9% of the cases.

Of course when writing scripts things **might** change. But even when writing scripts it's my opinion that people who mock UUoC ignore this important lessons by a great mind: *"Premature optimization is the root of all evil"*. And if you're not doing something atypical it's really hard for UUoC to be place where optimization will be needed. Of-course you *definitely need to know* what's inefficient about it (it's the extra process invocation BTW since few seem to mention it). Having that knowledge if you happen to work on those rare systems where invoking a process is expensive (e.g. some embedded systems or CygWin to a lesser degree) you will know what to do if a special situation requires it. For example if you find yourself calling `cat` many times a second in a loop (BTW if you do find yourself in that position ask yourself if bash is the right tool for the job). Again though: *"first make it work correctly then optimize it if necessary"*.

**And how do you explain the tsunami of complains about UUoC Nick?**

Besides not everyone having my taste I believe that a major part of why so many people complain about UUoC is not technical but human: Most Unix-newcomers will not know about the `< file command` idiom so it's tempting to a more experienced person to play the *"Old Guru"* to them. He will also have the opportunity to use fancy words ("process invocation") and touch the dear subject of "optimization". A good impression is guaranteed so it's very hard to resist. Then the newcomers will take the advice of the Guru at face value and for a long time will replay it to others as "The Only Truth" (and down-vote this answer :-). Funny note: it's probably so easy to fix bash to avoid any inefficiencies of UUoC that one has to wonder why nobody added this feature or made `< filename` cat a file after so many years. A dark soul would suggest that some graybeard bash hackers like to leave opportunities to mock us ;-)

Comment: +1 Love the last paragraph about why the anthropological factors that propagate this practice :-)

Answer (score 1):

What would be really nice is a shell that supports syntax like:

```
< filename cmd | cmd2 cmd2arg1... | cmd3
```

In the meantime, I think `cat filename | realcmd1...` is acceptable, as it keeps the syntax standardised with initial commands that require the filename as an argument.

Comment: Bash and similar shells support `< filename cmd | cmd2 ...`. Is that close enough?

Comment: @garyjohn: I think you should post that as an answer.

Comment: Ahh, I didn't know that garyjohn.  It's exactly what I meant actually (fixed), but I didn't know it was implemented :)

Comment: Obligatory old shell-hacker comment: Bourne-style shells have supported the `< file command ...` since at least the mid-80s and probably as far back as the 70s when the original `sh` was written.  More generally, i/o redirections are parsed left to right, and can be interspersed in any order within the command line.  So, `cmd <file arg arg...` would also be valid.

Comment: Yeah, it's partly because of how easy it is to type that that I invented the UUOC.

Comment: One shifted character vs. four unshifted isn't that big a difference, and I'd rather spawn an extra process, which even my *phone* barely notices, than pipe a file into my prompt, which gives me a headache every time I see it.

Answer (score 0):

For all who say cat is acceptable to use because it "smells" better or "is more readable" I would only say this:

To you maybe... but not to others who may read or try to understand your code.
If you will never ever try to instruct others with your examples or share your code, then by all means please use it at your own leisure.

I will also add this comment, as a long time Linux user and Admin/Engineer... (and there are many of us) it makes our eyes bleed to see this. Why? Because it uses resources on systems that we control resources tightly on. The cat command and the pipe itself use extra memory and file handles that are completely useless. You have tied up resources that my system needs free and you have gained NOTHING that can explain the usage of these resources. This is a huge no no.

Now I can sit here and debate things like code smell or readability all day with anyone, but at the end of the day it is a matter of write or wrong and any time you use resources on a system and gain nothing for it... it is wrong.

As a home user you can learn from my advice and learn better ways to do things or you can choose to be blinded by the "smell" of cats, your choice... but know that if you openly use this practice you will be called on this practice all the time and you will silently have to admit they are right and you are stubborn because it's true. :-)

Comment: I am also a long-time Linux (and earlier *nix) user and software developer. You do not speak for me when you say "it makes our eyes bleed" to see `cat foo.txt | ...`. The other answer explain well why it can be a good usage. The simple summary of the case in favour is: "$CPU time << $Brain time" (as @MikeP commented above).

Comment: First, that was an answer from 2017 (way to revive the dead lol).
Second, note that as an admin or developer we should always strive to minimize resource usage where possible. When writing apps and services you try to watch for memory or cpu drains that offer little or no benefit to the app/service correct? Well UUOC is exactly that. 

Now, there are perfectly valid uses of cat I am sure that involve piping to command... just not often.

So I may not speak for you, as you say... but if you are a professional I would wonder why you do not more readily agree (given a true UUOC scenario).

Comment: The issue is that memory or CPU drains are not the only cost for a developer to optimise. Cost of human time, to understand the problem and to write and debug an implementation, are also part of the tradeoff. Some of the answers here are based on a judgement that human time is way more scarce and expensive than memory or CPU. . … But this is becoming a discussion, which is against the rules. Let the votes on answers speak for which perspective is endorsed by Super Users.

Comment: "You have tied up resources that my system needs free and you have gained NOTHING that can explain the usage of these resources."  Even in in 2017, I'd have laughed at that, and asked if you also still shook your fist at emacs for being bloated, and only allowing nvi (never vim!) to be installed.