# Running mysql dump in a cron job without exposing passwords

Tags: security, cron

I want to run

```
mysqldump -u aUser -p P4SSw0rd --all-databases > backup.sql
```

in a cron job. How can I do so securely?

I know I could put the command right there, but anyone with access to the machine would see it straight away via crontab. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Your example is incorrect, it should be -pP4SSw0rd with no space.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As stated in `man mysqldump`: see [6.1.2.1. End-User Guidelines for Password Security](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/password-security-user.html) in the MySQL reference manual.

An option file is the safest bet, not least according to the above reference. Giving it in plaintext in crontab is not good, not least since the process command line by default is visible through `ps` for other users. The same actually applies for environment variables as explained in the reference.

#### Relevant portion of the MySQL reference manual:

> Store your password in an option file. For example, on Unix, you can list your password in the `[client]` section of the `.my.cnf` file in your home directory:
>
> ```
> [client]
> password=your_pass
> ```
>
> To keep the password safe, the file should not be accessible to anyone but yourself. To ensure this, set the file access mode to `400` or `600`. For example:
>
> ```
> shell> chmod 600 .my.cnf
> ```
>
> To name from the command line a specific option file containing the password, use the `--defaults-file=file_name` option, where `file_name` is the full path name to the file. For example:
>
> ```
> shell> mysql --defaults-file=/home/francis/mysql-opts
> ```
>
> Section [4.2.3.3, “Using Option Files”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/option-files.html), discusses option files in more detail.

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/10725209.

Comment: It seems that ps command obfuscate the password with one x: ps: mysqldump -uroot -px xx mydb. I'm not saying that it's a good protection though (if you type jobs, then the password is revealed in plain text).

Answer (score 4):

Run the cronjob as a specific user and use some simple Bash logic to extract the password from a plaintext file stored somewhere on the system with permissions that only allow the user (or perhaps group) to access it.

```
PASS=`cat /path/to/pwdfile`

 mysqldump -u aUser -p $PASS--all-databases > backup.sql
```

So if the cronjob runs as user 'example', the ownership of the file should be "example:example" and permissioned 0400.

You can also achieve a similar function using a user-level [.my.cnf](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/option-files.html).

Comment: `read PASS < /path/to/pwdfile` is a idiomatically cleaner to do the same thing (arguably I guess; http://superuser.com/q/323060/49184 applies).

Comment: \*"is AN idiomatically cleaner WAY"... Lost in editing.

Comment: Someone with even the most basic understanding of Bash should be able to see what's going on with that cat. :)

Comment: True, I would even say it is the most common way to do it, but it still a bit of an eyesore :-) . If one makes [UUOC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat) a habit it will bite when the file is bigger than `ARGMAX`, it takes an extra process instead of using a shell built-in, it might tempt constructs such as `for i in \`cat file\`; do ...` with its own array of problems, etc. But of course, as with most things: if one knows what is happening one is free to do as one chooses. I'm not on a crusade here, regardless of how it might appear :-D .

Answer (score 0):

Anyone with access to the machine has the same level of access to `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/` as to `/var/lib/mysql` you allow them to have. So, set the proper permissions on the directories and done. Anyone with root-access has direct access to the database files directly. Anyone you do not trust to have access to the machine should not have access at all to the machine.

Usually folks only see their own cronjobs via `crontab -l`.

Answer (score 0):

For backup purposes, consider having a *read-only* user in mysql, like so

```
CREATE USER bUser IDENTIFIED BY 'p4ss';

GRANT SELECT ON *.* TO bUser@localhost;
GRANT LOCK TABLES ON *.* TO bUser@localhost;
```

**mysqldump** requires only `SELECT` and `LOCK TABLES` privileges to do its job.