# Using grep on URLs not working

Tags: windows-7, command-line, grep

I've got a couple of text files (`a.txt` and `b.txt`) containing a bunch of URLs, each on a separate line. Think of these files as blacklists. I want to sanitize my `c.txt` file, scrubbing it of any of the strings in `a.txt` and `b.txt`. My approach is to rename `c.txt` to `c_old.txt`, and then build a new `c.txt` by grepping out the strings in `a.txt` and `b.txt`.

```
type c_old.txt | grep -f a.txt -v | grep -f b.txt -v > c.txt
```

For a long while, it seemed like my system was working just fine. However, lately, I've lost nearly everything that was in `c.txt`, and new additions are being removed despite not occurring in `a.txt` or `b.txt`. I have no idea why.

P.S. I'm on Windows 7, so grep has been installed separately. I'd appreciate it if there are solutions that don't require me to install additional Linux tools.

---

Update: I've discovered one mistake in my batch file. I used `ren c.txt c_old.txt` without realising that `ren` refuses to overwrite the target file if it exists. Thus, the `type c_old.txt | ...` always used the same data. This explains why new additions to `c.txt` were being wiped out, but it does not explain why so many entries that were in `c.txt` have gone missing.

Comment: A single `>` causes the text file to be overwritten each time, you would use `>>` to append to an existing file.

Comment: if you'd broken that down e.g. try `echo sdfsd >c.txt`  you'd have seen that > overwrites. And that it's thus not a grep problem. As techie said, use >>

Comment: The `>` is intentional. Appending would never remove any entries from c.txt, thus failing to eliminate entries in c.txt that also exist in a.txt or b.txt.

Comment: Thoughts: (1) Try `grep -f a.txt -v c_old.txt | grep -f b.txt -v > c.txt`, because `type … |` looks like [`cat … |`](http://superuser.com/questions/323060/what-is-the-general-consensus-on-useless-use-of-cat). (2) Try `grep -f a.txt -f b.txt -v c_old.txt > c.txt`. (Neither of these should make a difference in the result, but they are stylistically simpler.) …

Comment: … Then (3) Try adding `-F` (`--fixed-strings`) in case you’re getting any weird results where a `.` in `a.txt` or `b.txt` matches some other character in `c.txt`. (4) Check `a.txt` and `b.txt` to verify that neither of them has acquired a very short line (not a full URL) that’s matching lots of things. (5) Try to find a URL that’s getting stripped out, and find the line in `a.txt` or `b.txt` that’s causing that to happen.

Comment: perhaps to help track down the problem, would be.. Say you run that once a day? Then include in a bat file, a pause before and after and a check of the file size of c.txt.. you can check it by eye and make sure you haven't lost stuff from it unexpectedly, and if so then catch it near the time it happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't really have much data to go on, since there's not a huge number of new additions to a.txt and b.txt since I originally asked the question, but since fixing the `ren` issue (replaced it with `move /Y`), things have been working smoothly.

So, things are working better. I'm still not sure how the initial data loss happened, but it may be that I messed up at some point when editing the scripts, and didn't do my test runs in a safe environment.