# How to use HTML markup tags inside Bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I have crontab and a simple bash script that sends me emails every often containing PHP, NGINX, MYSQL errors from their log files. This is a simplified example.

```
#/home/user/status.sh
EMAIL=me@domain.com
  PHP_ERROR=`tail -5 /var/log/php-fpm/error.log`
  NGINX_ERROR=`tail -5 /var/log/nginx/error.log`
  MYSQL_ERROR=`tail /var/log/mysqld.log`
  DISK_SPACE=`df -h`
  echo "

Today's, server report::
==================================
    DISK_SPACE: $DISK_SPACE
 ---------------------------------
    MEMORY_USAGE: $MEMORY_USAGE
-----------------------------------
    NGINX ERROR: $NGINX_ERROR
-----------------------------------
    PHP ERRORS: $PHP_ERROR
------------------------------------
    MYSQL_ERRORS: $MYSQL_ERROR
-------------------------------------
 " | mail -s "Server reports" $EMAIL
```

I know this is a very basic usage, but as you can see, I am trying to separate the errors, but not of the html tags including `\n` are working.

So, my question is, is it possible to use HTML tags to format the text, if not .. then what are the alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

You can use whatever formatting your mail client can read. To encode your message better, use the `<<EOF` syntax:

```
#/home/user/status.sh
EMAIL=me@domain.com
PHP_ERROR=`tail -5 /var/log/php-fpm/error.log`
NGINX_ERROR=`tail -5 /var/log/nginx/error.log`
MYSQL_ERROR=`tail /var/log/mysqld.log`
DISK_SPACE=`df -h`
mail -s "Server reports" $EMAIL <<EOF
Today's, server report::
==================================
    DISK_SPACE:   $DISK_SPACE
----------------------------------
    MEMORY_USAGE: $MEMORY_USAGE
----------------------------------
    NGINX ERROR:  $NGINX_ERROR
----------------------------------
    PHP ERRORS:   $PHP_ERROR
----------------------------------
    MYSQL_ERRORS: $MYSQL_ERROR
----------------------------------
EOF
```

Comment: I just copy/pasted your script, and the HTML tags I added `<b>DISK_SPACE:</b> <u>MEMORY_USAGE</ul>` didn't have any effect. I can see the tags rendered in my email.

Comment: You might need to [add the proper `Content-Type` header](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15405/how-do-i-send-html-email-using-linux-mail-command)

Comment: Another [useless use of cat](http://superuser.com/q/323060/354511)! You could just as well do `mail -s "Server reports" "$EMAIL" <<EOF`.