# xargs run bash script with threads (2 arguments)

Tags: bash, shell-script, xargs

I have a file in the following format:

```
"192.168.2.1" "80"
"172.16.1.1" "443"
"10.1.1.1" "8080"
```

which contains multiple local IPs and i'm trying to run a script with threads using xargs to execute the following command:

```
cat local-IPs.txt|xargs -I % -P 100 python script.py % "execute command"
```

The problem I am facing right now is that since the local-IPs.txt file contains "IP" AND "port", the xargs command won't be able to take both (IP and PORT).

Any help would be very appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What command do you want to run? How would you pass it the IP and port if you were to run one manually?

Comment: python script.py 192.168.2.1 80 "/root/start-module.sh"

Answer (score 1):

If you can, edit `script.py` so it takes *IP* and *port* as its last arguments. Then you can use the `-n` (or `-L`) option of `xargs`:

```
<local-IPs.txt xargs -n 2 -P 100 python script.py "execute command"
```

<sup>([Useless use of `cat`](https://superuser.com/q/323060/432690) removed.)</sup>

To be clear, it will execute something like

```
python script.py "execute command" 192.168.2.1 80
```

therefore it's crucial `script.py` expects this form. Even if you cannot modify `script.py` itself, maybe you can copy it and work with the copy.

---

Another approach is to make `xargs` spawn a shell whose only job will be to change the sequence of arguments. This should work with *unmodified* `script.py`:

```
<local-IPs.txt xargs -n 2 -P 100 sh -c 'exec python script.py "$1" "$2" "execute command"' xargs-sh
```

There will be one `sh` per `python`. This may substantially decrease the performance.

Note there are now double-quotes inside single-quotes. It's good to know [how it affects expansion of parameters and variables](https://superuser.com/q/1404244/432690), especially if `execute command` contains some (your comment indicates it doesn't, but in general it may).

`xargs-sh` is explained [here](https://superuser.com/q/1526229/432690).