# sed Error sed: -e expression #1, char 7: unterminated `s' command

Tags: bash, sed

I keep switching between my command prompt and my git bash shell on windows 10. Suppose I copied my current directory to the clipboard in my command prompt(cmd.exe) and want to switch to that directory in my git bash, I wrote a function d2u() in my .bashrc file which converted the windows path to git bash path and executed it, that worked just fine.

```
anjan@DESKTOP-RPUVCRE MINGW64 /d
$ cat /dev/clipboard
D:\work\playground\reactNative
anjan@DESKTOP-RPUVCRE MINGW64 /d
$ type d2u
d2u is a function
d2u ()
{
    cat /dev/clipboard | sed -r "s'\\\\'/'g" | sed -r "s'^D:'/d'g" | sed -r "s'^C:'/c'g"
}

anjan@DESKTOP-RPUVCRE MINGW64 /d
$ pushd `d2u`
/d/work/playground/reactNative /d /d/work/playground/reactNative /d /d/work/playground/reactNative ~

anjan@DESKTOP-RPUVCRE MINGW64 /d/work/playground/reactNative
```

However, when I incrementally improved that to pushd to that unixy path in a new function cd2u, it bombs!

```
anjan@DESKTOP-RPUVCRE MINGW64 /d/work/playground/reactNative
$ type cd2u
cd2u is a function
cd2u ()
{
    pushd `cat /dev/clipboard | sed -r "s'\\\\'/'g" | sed -r "s'^D:'/d'g" |  sed -r "s'^C:'/c'g" `
}

anjan@DESKTOP-RPUVCRE MINGW64 /d/work/playground/reactNative
$ cd2u
sed: -e expression #1, char 7: unterminated `s' command
/d /d/work/playground/reactNative /d/work/playground/reactNative /d /d/work/playground/reactNative ~

anjan@DESKTOP-RPUVCRE MINGW64 /d
$
```

what gives ? why do I get this error ?

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 7: unterminated `s' command
```

My sed version is relatively new

$ sed --version
sed (GNU sed) 4.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because [backticks (``` `` ```) interpret backslashes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/5782/108618). This way your `\\\\` in backticks work like `\\` without backticks. Then they get to `sed` as `\`, because double-quoting also interprets backslashes. And ten `sed` interprets `\'` as *escaped* `'`.

Use `$()` instead of backticks. This syntax won't introduce additional level of interpreting backslashes. Nowadays `$()` should be your choice anyway.

And [quote](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618) (hint: double-quoting `$()` will not interfere with whatever quotes you have inside `$()`).

And [leave the `cat` alone](https://superuser.com/q/323060/432690).

<sub>Note: I'm neither reviewing nor going to review your `sed` expressions. They may be right for what you want to do, or wrong, or sub-optimal. I'm just explaining how moving backticks from the invocation of the function to the function body caused the error.</sub>

Comment: Thanks @Kamil Maciorowski : I know my sed is not optimal -- didn't have patience today to get it optimal. This is interactive usage so a few milliseconds here and there is ok and I don't use it very regularly.

Comment: Hi @Kamil Maciorowski : I Posted another question for optimizing the sed. Pls. take a look if you can help : https://superuser.com/questions/1583223/how-to-optimize-multiple-sed-commands-to-fewer-sed

Comment: I just get $() at the end of every line even though i've put $(\) in there.